# continue the loop after completion of the function called

Tags: javascript

Here I'm calling the function `testlike()` in each loop , the testlike function is called but before completion of that function the loop is completed ,after completion of loop inside the `DataServices.GetLikes(value).then(function (resp1) )` function is executing  , i want to continue the loop after completion of `testlike()` function in everytime calling

```
function getAllMessages() 
{
  DataServices.getAllMessages().then(function (resp) {
    if (resp.d.results.length > 0) {
      $.each(resp.d.results, function (key, val) { 
        testlike(val.Id);
      });
    }
  });
}

function testlike(value) 
{
  DataServices.GetLikes(value).then(function (resp1) {
    if (resp1.d.results.length > 0) {
      $.each(resp1.d.results, function (k, v) {
        if (value === v.MessageIdId) {
          $(".eventfire").removeClass("likeevent").addClass("unlikeevent");
          $(".unlikeevent").text("Unlike");
          $(".unlikeevent").attr("unlikeitem", v.Id);
        }
      });

      $(".unlikeevent").click(function () {
        unLikeevent($(this).attr("unlikeitem"));
      });
    }
  }, function (err) { alert(err) });
}
```

Comment: can u use async/await?

Answer (score 0):

Your, `testlike` function is *async*, but your `$.each` loop is *sync*.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand you correctly but will try my best

first of all you don't need to check if the array item as any length. just loop over the array and if it's empty it won't do anything.

Second, you don't need to use jQuery's `$.each` loop. Arrays has methods for that: [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

This will do all testlike in parallel and log `all done` when everything is complete

```
function getAllMessages() {
  DataServices.getAllMessages().then(function(resp) {
    // create a new array from results that are only promises
    var jobs = resp.d.results.map(function(val) { 
      return testlike(val.Id)
    })

    // Wait for all to complete
    Promise.all(jobs).then(function(results){
      // It's done
      console.log('all done')
    })
  })
}

function testlike(value) {
  // here i return the value/promise
  return DataServices.GetLikes(value).then(function (resp1) {
    resp1.d.results.forEach(function (v, k) {
      if (value === v.MessageIdId) {
        $(".eventfire").removeClass("likeevent").addClass("unlikeevent")
        $(".unlikeevent").text("Unlike").attr("unlikeitem", v.Id)
      }
    })

    $(".unlikeevent").click(function () {
      unLikeevent($(this).attr("unlikeitem"))
    })

  }, function (err) { 
    alert(err) 
  })
}
```

but if you want to do it one after the other, then i would change the getAllMessage to use async/await

```
async function getAllMessages() {
  var resp = DataServices.getAllMessages()

  for (let job of resp.d.results) {
    await testlike(val.Id)
  } 
}
```

but there is alternative methods as well if you need a es5 version
just comment here if you need one and i will make something up

Comment: thanks but your code also giving the same result which i got earlier ...my requirement is if once the testLike function called in eachfunction the entire testLike includes the DataServices.GetLikes(value).then(function (resp1) { code has to complete first and return  to loop .....same like in each loop repetition